# The page isn't redirecting properly searched a lot but cant find solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

im trying a simple routing and i have my global.asax as below

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    registerroutes(RouteTable.Routes);


}

public static void registerroutes(RouteCollection routecollection)
{
    routecollection.MapPageRoute("home","home/","~/home.aspx");
}
```

my home page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

    Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/home/"));



    }
}
```

but not not redirecting properly dont know where im wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Microsoft Friendly URL Nuget package? (If not, I'd highly suggest it)

If you use it you can avoid using the redirect in your homepage -

you need to create a RouteConfig.CS in App_Code>App_Start the add then following code (make sure you are using System.Web.Routing, and Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.MapPageRoute("", "", "~/default.aspx");            
    }
```

in the global.asax you then add

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);

}
```

This should then work without you needing any sort of redirect in the homepage.

Comment: im using system.web.routing

Comment: are you using the FriendlyURLs Nuget? if you use it and set the code as I have it will work for certain.

Comment: i have found the solution for first route there is no need to mention response.redirect so looping of route is not formed,   thanks for your help dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the ResolveUrl as it's not intended to be used here, it's only for resolving the scripts and resource files in the view / aspx code.

Response.Redirect("~/home");

One more thing, pay attention to C# coding standards , function names should be pascal case:
RegisterRoutes instead of registerroutes

Also, make sure you have a physical file for the home.aspx page that is placed on the root of your website.

If it's still not wroking, we need to know what kind of error you are getting and how you are running your app ? using the IIS express ? or IIS server ? or the classic development server ?

Comment: still not working the error is The page isn't redirecting properly